# Add a rule to .jshintrc to search for a wrong string

Tags: javascript, jshint

Is it possible to make a rule inside a `.jshintrc` file so that some string wouldn't be allowed when checking files?

Sometimes I get wrong modules imports that Webstorm creates on `Alt + Enter`.

These look like this:

```
import {someModule} from "../Common/myModules";
```

So, if it contains a substring `from "../Common/`, it's wrong and the check should fail.

Is it possible to make it work?